# Bulk Insert Varying Column Numbers in CSV File

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, bulkinsert

I am trying to use a BULK INSERT to import data from a CSV file into a table. Below is my working Stored Procedure to accomplish this:

```
USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[delete_fill]
    AS

    TRUNCATE TABLE dataImport

    BULK
    INSERT dataImport
    FROM 'c:\fileshare\temp.CSV'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )

    SELECT * FROM dataImport ORDER BY StoreID, ItemID
    RETURN
```

Now I have potentially added 2 new columns to the CSV file. How do I modify my stored procedure in order to account for the two new columns while accepting files with only three columns, leaving the two new columns null in the database.

Simply adding two columns to the table dataImport and running the procedure does not work. I receive this error: "Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Procedure delete_fill, Line 7
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 3 (Price)."

dataImport structure and csv data example as requested:

```
Create table dataImport(
StoreID BIGINT not null,
ItemID BIGINT not null,
Price money not null,
TwoforQuantity Int,
TwoforPrice money
)
```

3 Columns:

```
StoreID, ItemID, Price
133,51425,11.79
133,80277,1.49
133,15544,5.28
```

5 Columns:

```
StoreID, ItemID, Price, IntField, MoneyField
133,51425,11.79,2,20.99
133,80277,1.49,2,2.00
133,15544,5.29,3,14.99
```

Comment: Read this, same situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601941/bulk-insert-with-inconsistent-number-of-columns

Comment: Sorry, should have included it originally: Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Procedure delete_fill, Line 7
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 3 (Price)

Comment: Thanks, I've read that, and this is not the same situation. My columns will not vary within the file. Either the file will have 3 columns, or 5. Hoping for a better solution than in the above.

Comment: I've decided to do the following:

I'm starting the stored procedure from a VB.Net app so I am going to check the number of columns in the file before the upload to the server. Then I will add a parameter to the SP which is the number of columns in the file (it will always be either 3 or 5). Add two tables to the DB - one with 3 columns, one with 5. Depending on the columns parameter I'll fill and return different tables.

If anyone has a more elegant solution please let me know. :D

Comment: Can you post sample data from your file and table structure of dataImport?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue a while back. Here’s a rough overview of how we addressed it:

- Data file contained X number of columns, where the columns were effectively in random order
- First row listed the columns, following rows contained data
- Table contains Y columns. Barring the primary key columns, no assumptions could be made regarding what columns were in which set

Solution:

- BULK INSERT the first row only as a single column (no column delimiter) to a varchar(max)
- Parse it, identify columns (and order!) in file
- Add columns to table as necessary (ATLER TABLE). Big issue when we run out of columns, but that’s another story.
- Create a view on the table, listing only those columns present, ordered as per the file but “mapped” to the correct columns in the table
- Columns not in the view default to NULL. (Or, if not nullable, you have to set up default constraints)
- Yes, we used a lot of dynamic SQL
- BULK INSERT rows 2 and up into the view

You may have to write a lot of infrastructure to manage all this. For each run:
 - If view exists, drop it
 - If “loading defaults” exist, drop them
 - Proceed as above

(I leave the “last round” of views and stuff in place, for debugging purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

If columns number in file is fixed (either 3 or 5) and table have 5 columns then -

1. Find the total number of columns in file - you can use different approach for this. Either find it before uploading file or just `BULK INSERT` the first row and count it.
2. Create temporary table based on the number of columns
3. Then `BULK INSERT' to temporary table.
4. Then finally you can insert the data from temporary table to main table.

You need to use dynamic query.

Your query will look something like -

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @column_number INT
SET @column_number = 5 -- OR 3

IF @column_number = 3
BEGIN
    SET @sql = ' 
            create table #tmp (
                StoreID varchar(100),
                ItemID varchar(100),
                Price varchar(100)
            );'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @sql = ' 
            create table #tmp (
                StoreID varchar(100),
                ItemID varchar(100),
                Price varchar(100),
                IntField varchar(100),
                MoneyField varchar(100)
            );'
END

SET @sql = @sql + ' BULK INSERT #tmp
                    FROM ''c:\fileshare\temp.CSV''
                    WITH
                    (
                    FIRSTROW = 2,
                    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                    )'

SET @sql = @sql + ' IF ' + CAST(@column_number AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' = 3
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO dataImport (StoreID, ItemID, Price)
                        SELECT StoreID, ItemID, Price FROM #tmp
                    END
                    ELSE IF ' + CAST(@column_number AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' = 5
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO dataImport (StoreID, ItemID, Price, IntField, MoneyField)
                        SELECT StoreID, ItemID, Price, IntField, MoneyField FROM #tmp
                    END'
EXEC(@sql)
```