# BULK INSERT ROWTERMINATOR \n in widechar CSV is ignored when ending columns omitted

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, unicode, bulkinsert

I have what I take for a correctly formatted CSV - it is unicode tab delimited CSV delimited with CRLF, hex `00 0D 00 0A` - see Notepad++ picture bellow:

[image]

When I run SQL command from SSMS 2016 on SQL Server 2008 (10.0.2531.0):

```
    BULK
     INSERT #ZCSD84
     FROM 'x:\ZCSD84.csv'
     WITH
     (
     FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
     FIRSTROW = 1,
     CODEPAGE = 1250,
     DATAFILETYPE='widechar'
     )
```

I get good results except for the rows where there are tabs ommited at the end of the CSV record. There I get two rows incorrectly merged into one row as shown bellow. Even the first column value from the following row is added to the last column value of the row creating a value of e.g. `Jednorázový zákazník CB30`.

[image]

I have tried to specify various other rowterminators like `0x0A` but with theese I get allways `The bulk load failed. The column is too long ...` error.

How to force the new table row to be created as soon as CRLF is encoutered? Or some other workaround like to prepare more CSV correctly?

Comment: Should your row terminator not be `\r\n`?

Comment: Does not work for me, it throws the mentioned error. Found a related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2601941/2224701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604929/2224701) that shows there will be probably no simple solution for this problem. I have decided to fix CSV before bulk inserting using C# console app and [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which was quite simple:

```
class Program
{
    public class ZCSD84
    {
        public string PrOrg { get; set; }
        public string Odberatel { get; set; }
        public string Dodavatel { get; set; }
        public string Jmeno1 { get; set; }
        public string Jmeno2 { get; set; }
        public string Ulice { get; set; }
        public string PSC { get; set; }
        public string Misto { get; set; }
        public string MistniCast { get; set; }
        public string DIC { get; set; }
        public string ICO { get; set; }
        public string StareCislo { get; set; }
        public string HeadOffice { get; set; }
        public string HeadOfficeName { get; set; }
        public string Payer { get; set; }
        public string PayerName { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class ZCSD84Map : CsvClassMap<ZCSD84>
    {
        public ZCSD84Map()
        {
            Map(m => m.PrOrg).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.Odberatel).Index(1);
            Map(m => m.Dodavatel).Index(2);
            Map(m => m.Jmeno1).Index(3);
            Map(m => m.Jmeno2).Index(4);
            Map(m => m.Ulice).Index(5);
            Map(m => m.PSC).Index(7);
            Map(m => m.Misto).Index(8);
            Map(m => m.MistniCast).Index(9);
            Map(m => m.DIC).Index(10);
            Map(m => m.ICO).Index(11);
            Map(m => m.StareCislo).Index(12);
            Map(m => m.HeadOffice).Index(13);
            Map(m => m.HeadOfficeName).Index(14);
            Map(m => m.Payer).Index(15);
            Map(m => m.PayerName).Index(17);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file1 = @"C:\JOBS\ZCSD84.csv";
        string file1Out = @"C:\JOBS\ZCSD84_out.csv";

        if (!File.Exists(file1))
            throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Soubor csv nelze otevřít {0}.", file1));

        List<ZCSD84> ZCSD84s;
        CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
        config.Delimiter = "\t";
        config.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
        config.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        config.DetectColumnCountChanges = false;
        config.IgnoreReadingExceptions = false;
        config.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
        config.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
        Encoding ce = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
        config.Encoding = ce;
        config.QuoteNoFields = true;

        config.RegisterClassMap<ZCSD84Map>();
        Console.WriteLine(file1);
        using (CsvReader csvIn = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file1), config))
        {
            ZCSD84s  = csvIn.GetRecords<ZCSD84>().ToList();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(file1Out);
        using (CsvWriter csvOut = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(file1Out, false, ce), config))
        {
            csvOut.WriteRecords(ZCSD84s);
        }
    }
}
```