# Can you cancel a BULK INSERT of all VARCHARs when a line's field count is incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delimiter, bulkinsert

I'm using a BULK INSERT to load delimited .txt files into a staging table with 5 columns. The .txt files can sometimes contain errors and have more/less than 5 fields per line. If this happens, is it possible to detect it and cancel the entire BULK INSERT?

Each table column is of type VARCHAR. This was done because header (H01) and line (L0101, L0102, etc...) rows contain fields with different types. Because of this, setting MAXERRORS = 0 doesn't seem to be working as there are technically no syntax errors. As a result the transaction is committed, the catch block never activates and the rollback doesn't occur. Lines still get inserted into the table incorrectly shifted or bunched.

```
Expected .txt file format:

H01|Order|Date|Name|Address
L0101|Order|Part|SKU|Qty
L0102|Order|Part||Qty            <-- Fields can be blank
L0103|Order|Part|SKU|Qty

Incorrect .txt file example:

H01|Order|Date|Name|Address
L0101|Order||Part|SKU|Qty        <-- Extra field in the middle
||L0102|Order|Part|SKU|Qty       <-- Extra fields at the beginning
L0103|Order|Part|SKU|Qty||       <-- Extra fields at the end
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStage (

     Column1    VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,Column2    VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,Column3    VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,Column4    VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,Column5    VARCHAR(255) NULL
)

DECLARE 
     @dir           SYSNAME
    ,@fname         SYSNAME
    ,@SQL_BULK      VARCHAR(255)

SELECT 
     @dir           =   '\\sharedfolder\'
    ,@fname         =   'testOrder.txt'


SET @SQL_BULK = 
        'BULK INSERT #TempStage FROM ''' + @dir + @fname + ''' WITH
        (
            FIRSTROW = 1,
            DATAFILETYPE=''char'',
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'',
            KEEPNULLS,
            MAXERRORS = 0
        )'

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        EXEC (@SQL_BULK)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH

SELECT * FROM #TempStage
DROP TABLE #TempStage
```

Expected output:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H01 | Order | Date | Name | Address |
| L0101 | Order | Part | SKU | Qty |
| L0102 | Order | Part | *NULL* | Qty |
| L0103 | Order | Part | SKU | Qty |

Incorrect output, would like to cancel so this doesn't happen (\ = pipe):

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H01 | Order | Date | Name | Address |
| L0101 | Order | *NULL* | Part | SKU \ Qty |
| *NULL* | *NULL* | L0102 | Order | Part \ SKU \ QTY |
| L0103 | Order | Part | SKU | Qty\ | |

SQL Server 2016, 13.0.1742.0

Comment: Missing (not blank) fields typically cause BULK INSERT to abort and fail (as do extra fields).  To extend it to blank fields, changing your target table to disallow NULLs should do it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I would do this, however fields can be NULL if not used (SKU can be NULL for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a basic way to do what I needed:

After loading the staging table, check for any instance of '|' (or whatever delimiter you're using), and raise an error if found.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TempStage WHERE
        Column1 LIKE '%|%'
        OR Column2 LIKE '%|%'
        OR Column3 LIKE '%|%'
        OR Column4 LIKE '%|%'
        OR Column5 LIKE '%|%'
)
RAISERROR('Incorrect file formatting; Pipe character found.', 16, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As many before have noted: BULK INSERT is fast, but [not very flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601941/bulk-insert-with-inconsistent-number-of-columns), especially to column inconsistencies.

When your input might have bad data (and technically, from a SQL standpoint that is what you are describing), you have to employ one or more of some different approaches:

1. Pre-process and "clean" the data with an external program first, or
2. BULK INSERT to a staging table with one big VARCHAR(MAX) column, and then parse and clean the data yourself with SQL before moving it into tables with your real columns, or
3. Use CLR code/tricks to effectively to (1) and/or (2) above, or
4. Write an external program to simultaneously clean/pre-process and SqlBulkCopy the data into your SQL Server (replacing BULK INSERT), or
5. Use SSMS instead (still pretty hard to deal with bad/variable columns though)

I have done all of these at one time or another during my career, and they are all somewhat difficult and time-consuming (the *work* was time-consuming, their run-times were pretty good).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I ended up doing a modified version of #2. After loading my staging table I checked for any instance of '|' and raised an error if found. No need to clean the data since we are just moving the file into a designated error folder.